# When I'm using RequestDispatcher, instead of processing contents of JSP, JSP page as whole is being rendered on output

Tags: jsp, servlets

When I'm calling RequestDispatcher, instead of processing request, JSP page itself is being rendered as output...JSP content is present after "Account Created" line.

//Servlet block

```
if(i==1){
            PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
            pw.println("Account Created!!");
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);
            System.out.println("Record Updated!!!");
        }
```

//Output rendered on browser:

```
Account Created!!

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico"></link> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"></link>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="./Authentication" method="post">
    <p>Enter username<input type="text" name="Uname"></p>
    <p>Enter password<input type="password" name="Pword"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be getting the writer in the servlet and you should not be manually writing a string to it and you should be using `RequestDispatcher#forward()` instead of `include()`. You're otherwise preventing JSP from setting the proper `text/html` content type and hence everything is interpreted as plain text by the webbrowser.

Rewrite that servlet block as follows to let JSP do its job properly:

```
if (i == 1) {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains Hello World examples of properly using servlets

Comment: @BalusC...could you please let me know why include is not working in this case?

Comment: Because JSP couldn't set the proper `text/html` content type. Read the javadoc of `include()`: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse) You were after all just using the wrong way of forwarding the control to JSP. The `include()` isn't there for and you should not be getting the response writer in the servlet at all, it is not the responsibility of the servlet.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not setting contentType to your response before sending it to browser.

set `response.setContentType("text/html");` it should work for you. :)